# How to run in a loop for column A , find a value and print the corresponding data from column B

Tags: excel, powershell

I am working on xlsx file and i need to read values from column A and display the values in column B
For an example column A has 100 rows and some of them have a string. At column B (Also 100 rows) i have also values. I want to run in a loop a search for all the cells in column A, Store them and print the corresponding values in column B

[image]

I want to search for # and display 1,2,7 from B
I need an object that holds the values from A and object for B (For further actions)

The code below search in all the columns and display the values.
What i need is to read only from a specific column. and i need an object that holds the values from A and B

$data holds the data of column A.
I want to in a loop and search for data and then display the same data in the same row in column B?

```
$ExcelFile = "C:\Temp\SharedFolder\Test.xlsx" 
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.visible = $false
$Excel.DisplayAlerts = $False # Disable comfirmation prompts
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($ExcelFile)

$data = $workbook.Worksheets['Sheet1'].UsedRange.Rows.Columns[1].Value2
```

Comment: Please tell us in what type of file these columns are. A CSV file? Excel maybe? Then of course, explain what you have tried **yourself** already, what didn't work and if any, show us the error messages you received. This platform is all about people helping you with **your** code. Oh yes, before I forget. Use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71196196/edit) link underneath your question to add the needed info, do not give us all that in comments.

Comment: Someone please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this in Excel can be done, but takes a bit more work.

If this is your Excel file:

[image]

```
$ExcelFile   = "D:\Test\Test.xlsx" 
$searchValue = '@'

$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.Visible = $false
$Excel.DisplayAlerts = $False # Disable comfirmation prompts
$workbook  = $excel.Workbooks.Open($ExcelFile)
$worksheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)

# get the number of rows in the sheet
$rowMax = $worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

# loop through the rows to test if the value in column 1 equals whatever is in $searchValue
# and capture the results in variable $result
$result = for ($row = 1; $row -le $rowMax; $row++) {
    $val = $worksheet.Cells.Item($row, 1).Value2
    if ($val -eq $searchValue) {
        # output an object with both values from columns A and B
        [PsCustomObject]@{A = $val; B = $worksheet.Cells.Item($row, 2).Value2}
    }
}

# when done, quit Excel and remove the used COM objects from memory (important)
$excel.Quit()
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($worksheet)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($workbook)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel)
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

Now you can process the objects in `$result`. For demo just output:

```
$result
```

```
A B
- -
@ 1
@ 2
@ 7
```

Of course, it would be far easier if you save your Excel file as CSV..

```
$searchValue = '@'
$result = Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\Test.csv' -UseCulture | Where-Object { $_.A -eq $searchValue }

$result
```

When exporting an Excel file to Csv, Excel won't always use the *comma* as delimiter character. That depends on your machine's local settings. This is the reason I added switch `-UseCulture` to the Import-Csv cmdlet which will make sure it uses the same delimiter character your locally installed Excel uses for its output.

Comment: Thank you very much
So after I have the $Result, How can I run foreach loop for an example on B and do something with them?

$searchValue = '@'
$result = Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\Test.csv' -UseCulture | Where-Object { $_.A -eq $searchValue }

$result

Comment: Regarding to your answer for the xlsx file. it is possible to holds to objects. 1 for  column A and one for B. Again for foreach loop

Comment: @NirCarmona Your first question: You specifically asked for **objects**, so you just use the properties of these in `$result` like `$result | where-Object { $_.B -eq 7 }` for instance. As for the xlsx file, this works for me as expected. I wil post an image of what the Excel file looks like (using your example). If your _real_ excel file differs, then you should have given a better example.

Comment: @NirCarmona Thanks, I guess my answer helped you then. If your Excel file has values in column A like email addresses like `Nir.Carmona@yourdomain.com` (which could be the reason to search for the `@` character), then change `-eq $searchValue` in the codes into `-like '*$searchValue*'` or `-match $searchValue`, so you are looking for any string **containing** that character.

Comment: Thank you Theo :)
I need an object that i can run one by one and do something with it.  Now its clear?
Second 
How to sum cells with a specific background color in a specific column?

Comment: Thank you again
My real goal is to find a background color in cell in a specific column and get all the corresponding row from different column. Then run in a loop on the result and do something with them

Comment: I am trying to run on the list like this but i get a list of all the results. I want to take each one of the $res and use it in a different function
$result
foreach ($res in $result)
{
    $res
}

Comment: Regarding to this answer. I get in the result both column. How can i get only one column? because I need to run in a loop on the result (one column)
Thanks


$searchValue = '@'
$result = Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\Test.csv' -UseCulture | Where-Object { $_.A -eq $searchValue }

$result

Comment: @NirCarmona inside your loop just use the property (column) of choice using dot notation: `foreach ($res in $result) { $res.B ... }` or `$res.A`, whichever property you need of course. This is the way you refer to properties of objects in PowerShell

Comment: Regarding to your first answer I want to add something more.
When I have the $Result that holds all the number from column called patch. so if i write $Result.patch i get only the number.
For each number i need to add a string so i try to use -join, I need that $vars will contain the number at the end of the string like
\\google.com\global\Patch Managment\2
How can i do this? Thanks

$result
foreach ($res in $result)
{
    $res.patch
}
$vars = -join("\\google.com\global\Patch Managment\",$res.patch)

Comment: @NirCarmona simply have your loop output the combined string and capture that in $vars:  `$vars = foreach ($res in $result) { "\\google.com\global\Patch Managment\$($res.patch)" }`. You need to wrap `$res.patch` inside a subexpression `$()` to have that value resolved

Comment: Hi Theo
Do you have any idea how to search by background color for xlsx?  It will be great for me

Comment: @NirCarmona You would have to look for a cell's ColorIndex property. You can look up which value belongs to what color here: [ColorIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.ColorIndex).
So if you are looking for red cells, you can use `$val = $worksheet.Cells.Item($row, 1).Interior.ColorIndex; if ($val -eq 3) { ... }`. For any further questions, I suggest you post a new question please.

Comment: It is possible to replace the 2 (column) by the name of the column?

$val = $worksheet.Cells.Item($row, 2)

Comment: @NirCarmona No, you need to use the columns **index** number there. There are ways of finding it of course. but really, that's another question

Comment: Hi Theo
This is working great for me and gets all the green cells
And I changed the name to patch
[PsCustomObject]@{Patch = $worksheet.Cells.Item($row, 1).Value2}
But now I need 2 objects. One for all the greens and anther one for the greens + who has the string "CAB". For each one i need to run a loop in order to copy them to a remote path. How can i do that?

Comment: Regarding to my question above. Just to make clear. I need to hold all the green cells that i have already and get all the green cells that has the string 'CAB' inside the cell. 
This is very important to me